# Select multiple tr based on provided data attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all rows which have data-attribute id with 1,2.. I can do so by specifying each row seperatly but it isn't best way of doing it, can someone put me in right direction please ?

```
<table id="eTable">
  <tr data-empid="A123" data-salary="120" data-status="drone">
    <td>Peter</td><td>Vogel</td><td>Principal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-empid="B456" data-salary="130" data-status="worker">
    <td>Jan</td><td>Vogel</td><td>General Manager</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-empid="C789" data-salary="110" data-status="worker">
    <td>Jason</td><td>van de Velde</td><td>Company nurse</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Selector**

```
var getFromWebServices = //GetFromWebServices() //result lets assume A123; B456
$("#eTable tr[data-empid='A123; B456']").hide(); // hide is here for an example, I want to get object with all rows for matching IDs
```

**I want it to be dynamic. I want this selector to get rows with empid A123; B456  in this specific case**

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/2/

**Edit**

Why is this not returning all rows but one by one,
http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/10/

Comment: do you want to hide tr for which `data-empid` is present?

Comment: Try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute selector can only deal with one value at a time, so you would need to use two selectors, separated by a comma:

```
$("#eTable tr[data-empid='A123'], #eTable tr[data-empid='B456']").hide();
```

If you are looking for the value programmatically, you could put them in an array use `filter()`:

```
var values = [ 'A123', 'B456' ];
$('#eTable tr').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).data('empid'), values) != -1;
}).hide();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you get the ids in an array (idArray), execute a `for` loop and hide each element with the respective data-empid:

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456'];
for (var i=0;i<idArray.length;i++) {
   var id = idArray[i];
   $("#eTable tr[data-empid=" + id + "]").hide();
}
```

Comment: You missed var before `i`.

Answer (score 1):

use `filter()` to  filter the `data-empid` elements and check each value is present in array using `indexOf()`

```
var arr = ['A123', 'B456']
$("#eTable tr[data-empid]").filter(function () {
    return arr.indexOf($(this).attr('data-empid')) != -1;
}).hide();
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6sx2313/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var getFromWebServices = ['A123', 'B456'];
$("#eTable tr[data-empid=" + getFromWebServices.join("], #eTable tr[data-empid=") + "]").hide();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<table id="eTable">
  <tr data-empid="A123" data-salary="120" data-status="drone">
    <td>Peter</td><td>Vogel</td><td>Principal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-empid="B456" data-salary="130" data-status="worker">
    <td>Jan</td><td>Vogel</td><td>General Manager</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-empid="C789" data-salary="110" data-status="worker">
    <td>Jason</td><td>van de Velde</td><td>Company nurse</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```